# Regarding the Link / text / image that stays static even when the webpage is scrolled

Tags: java, php, javascript, user-interface

are there any Java script or any sample available for the Link / text / image that stays static even when the webpage is scrolled.

I am looking for something similar to the one on the bottom left side of the webpage borders(Helpful?, "Yes", "No").

http://www.ehow.com/facebook-for-business/

Regards,
Gourav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code this may help you. but this code required lot more css and javascript code to make this same as ehow.

```
<style>
.mainDiv {
  height: 1000px;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
}
.fixDiv {
  height: 250px;
  width: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
</style>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="fixDiv">h e l p f u l l? Yes No</div>
  <div class="mainDiv">Gaurav</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav... Whats the name of this? is there any keyword that i can use to search in google

Comment: I made this according to your requirement. But definitely you get code for this if you search on google.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using simple css

create a style for div with id="poll" and give this style

div#poll {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 100px;
}

```
<div id="poll">
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image" class="contimage" border="0"/></div>
```

This div will be shown in the left side of the window